# install and import tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, installation

I am going mad for installing and import tensorflow for 6 weeks. I did everything; I installed it from spyder, Conda prompt and with different commands like `pip install tensorflow` and `conda install tensorflow`. my python version is 3.7 and after install when I want to import tensorflow in spyder I get this message:

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-d6579f534729>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\sally\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio

  File "C:\Users\sally\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav

  File "C:\Users\sally\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *

  File "C:\Users\sally\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 9, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database

  File "C:\Users\sally\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\symbol_database.py", line 184, in <module>
    _DEFAULT = SymbolDatabase(pool=descriptor_pool.Default())

AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor_pool' has no attribute 'Default
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue. I have been there.

First: provide the following information:
- what operating system?
- do you want to run on cpu or gpu?
- if gpu, what gpu do you have?
- are your drivers up to date?
- Are your trying to run tensorflow though an IDE like Pycharm, is it more like Jupyter notebook stuff, or just cmd.

Second: There are some link that might be usefull. Here they are.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements

There is a video that helped me, it might help you as well. With tensorflow it is really important to follow the instructions precisely, not missing any steps, and very important, not assuming that installing something with a higher version is no issue. If it says install 'whatever program'.version.1.1.x you can not install 'whatever program'.version.1.1.y

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrkEYf-YDyI&t=1575s